# Webform design and component alignment

Tags: webform-civicrm

we have created the new webform and included custom fields. we need to align the components styles(like width,background)etc. Any one please help us how to change the design. Thanks,kanchana.

Comment: Quite a few themes have a lot of CSS that is used to style forms. The CSS often overrides the field width values that you set within the webform. So I think I would start with the site CSS. There is also the webform layout module and a couple of webform bootstrap layout modules for Drupal.

Comment: Can you please explain how to access file  where to get ftp path in my civicrm site.

Comment: This is not really a CiviCRM issue - it's an issue with your hosting account and you need to investigate FTP access with your provider.